# android how to login to facebook through code

Tags: android, facebook

I want in my android app I can signin to facebook and also post texts.
I dont have any idea about that, how can I do that plz suugest me any way and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start this using this [facebook android](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android). Hope that's what you are looking for.